# Search for a string & display the information from the row that the found string belongs to in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am experiencing problems when dealing with CSV files using Python.

Can somebody help me with an example code that has these requirements:

1. Search a string;
2. Shows the results;
3. Prints the row in a formatted way in which the found string belongs to.

Example:
The table from "example.csv" file:

```
ID | First Name | Surname | Subject | Score
01 | Martin     | Brown   | Maths   | 58
02 | Richard    | Jones   | IT      | 59
03 | Martin     | Pickard | Music   | 95
```

The string is "martin"

The result should be

```
ID: 01
First Name: Martin
Surname: Brown
Subject: Maths
Score: 58

ID: 03
First Name: Martin
Surname: Pickard
Subject: Music
Score: 95
```

Thank you in advance.
Please help me with showing suggestions with a code.

Comment: sorry but this is outside the code writing service opening hours

Comment: So, when are the code writing service opening hours?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `example.csv` really does have `|` characters as you have shown, the following should work. It uses Python's CSV library to help with parsing the CSV file into column entries. Each row is read in and any extra spaces are removed. Next the user is prompted to enter a search string. The script then does a case insensitive search on all of the columns for a match. For each row that is found, it prints the output correctly formatted:

```
import csv

data = []

with open('example.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|')
    next(csv_input) # skip the header

    for row in csv_input:
        data.append([c.strip() for c in row])

search = raw_input("Please enter search: ").lower()

for row in data:
    if search in [c.lower() for c in row]:
        print "\nID: {}\nFirst Name: {}\nSurname: {}\nSubject: {}\nScore: {}".format(*row)
```

For example:

```
Please enter search: martin

ID: 01
First Name: Martin
Surname: Brown
Subject: Maths
Score: 58

ID: 03
First Name: Martin
Surname: Pickard
Subject: Music
Score: 95
```